# why is Numba parallel is slower than normal python loop?

Tags: python, numba

Following is normal python loop (I copied example from official doc - https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html)

```
def two_d_array_reduction_prod(n):
    shp = (13, 17)
    result1 = 2 * np.ones(shp, np.int_)
    tmp = 2 * np.ones_like(result1)

    for i in range(n):
        result1 *= tmp

    return result1
```

I called function like:

```
two_d_array_reduction_prod(50000)
```

It takes around 0.7482060070033185.

Numba parallel code

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def two_d_array_reduction_prod(n):
    shp = (13, 17)
    result1 = 2 * np.ones(shp, np.int_)
    tmp = 2 * np.ones_like(result1)

    for i in nb.prange(n):
        result1 *= tmp

    return result1
```

I called function like:

```
two_d_array_reduction_prod(50000)
```

It takes 3.9858204890042543

My environment:

1. Amazon Linux 2, x86_64 processor
2. 8 CPUs
3. 32G memory

Comment: What about subsequent calls? Maybe what you're seeing is the compile time.

Comment: two_d_array_reduction_prod(50000), also updated question

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this. Using `parallel=True` gives a slight performance improvement, but any method is significantly faster compared to pure Python for me.

Using:

```py
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np

def two_d_array_reduction_prod(n):
    shp = (13, 17)
    result1 = 2 * np.ones(shp, np.int_)
    tmp = 2 * np.ones_like(result1)

    for i in prange(n): # or for i in range(n):
        result1 *= tmp

    return result1

two_d_array_reduction_prod_numba = nb.njit(parallel=False)(two_d_array_reduction_prod)
```

Even with `parallel=False` with `prange` or using `parallel=False` with `range` I get over 3x improvement. All these timings are done with a warm-up, pre-compiling the Numba function first.

[image: ZT6TN]

Comment: Thanks Rutger, it works in notebook for me as well. However, it doesn't work when I have code an simple .py file and execute file from shell like $python numbatest.py. I used time.perf_counter() get time difference before after two_d_array_reduction_prod(50000)

Comment: Do you then include compilation time for Numba? You can exclude that by calling the function before (outside perf_counter()) with the same types. If that's the reason, and an issue, perhaps `cache=True` might be someting to consider:  https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/caching.html

Comment: settign cache true helped for 2nd run -> 0.012247410999999708 (first run is significantly slow even with cache=True). More interestingly setting signature helped a lot -> 0.002675978000000079